# organize array when data changes

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, sorting, angularjs-scope

I have an array in a $scope variable that looks like this:

```
$scope.objects: [
  {selected: true, description: 'string1'},
  {selected: false, description: 'string2'},
  {selected: true, description: 'string3'},
  {selected: true, description: 'string4'}
]
```

The "selected" property can be changed by checkboxes rendered in the UI.

I'm looking for a method to watch the "selected" properties in the array. Every time it changes, the array needs to be reordered.

The objects with "selected:false" need to be put on the end of the array. The array above would look like this.

```
$scope.objects: [
  {selected: true, description: 'string1'},
  {selected: true, description: 'string3'},
  {selected: true, description: 'string4'},
  {selected: false, description: 'string2'}
]
```

if, for example the selected-value of the second element is changed to false, the array should look like this:

```
$scope.objects: [
  {selected: true, description: 'string1'},      
  {selected: true, description: 'string4'},
  {selected: false, description: 'string3'},
  {selected: false, description: 'string2'}
]
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Greetz

Comment: Does it matter in which order the true / false alternatives are listed?

Comment: yes, the order of the true/false objects need to be the same is the original array

Answer (score 1):

You should write a filter that does the sorting for you.

I would try something like this, using [lodash](https://lodash.com/).
The snippet is not tested or anything, just written in notepad, but it could give you a startingpoint.

```
app.filter('sortSelected', function() {
    return function(items) {
        var groups = _.groupBy(items, 'selected');
    };
    var selected = _.sortBy(groups[true], 'description');
    var unselected = _.sortBy(groups[false], 'description');

    return selected.concat(unselected);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

The answer is based on Pjetr's idea.

In the UI (and the ng-repeat that loops over the array):

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-change="orderUnselected()" ng-model="object.selected">
```

in the controller:

```
$scope.orderUnselected = function() {
    var trues = [];
    var falses = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.objects.length; i++) {
        var obj = $scope.objects[i];
        if(obj.selected == true) {
            trues.push(obj);
        } else {
            falses.push(obj);
        }
    }

    $scope.objects = trues.concat(falses);
}
```

This sollution works and doesn't bring up any scope errors.